# [QCOM-MSM8916][CM12.1] How to register correct framebuffer nodes? (fb0/1/2)

Tags: android, c++, c, framebuffer, cyanogenmod

I'm the current developer for Samsung Galaxy J5.

- **Chipset**: Qualcomm MSM8916 Snapdragon 410
- **CPU**: Quad-core 1.2 GHz Cortex-A53
- **GPU**: Adreno 306

In **/hardware/qcom/display-caf/msm8916/libqdutils** there is the corresponding file, (**qd_utils.cpp**) to declare the framebuffer nodes through **msm_fb_type**.

```
#include "qd_utils.h"
#define QD_UTILS_DEBUG 0

namespace qdutils {

int getHDMINode(void)
{
    FILE *displayDeviceFP = NULL;
    char fbType[MAX_FRAME_BUFFER_NAME_SIZE];
    char msmFbTypePath[MAX_FRAME_BUFFER_NAME_SIZE];
    int j = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < HWC_NUM_DISPLAY_TYPES; j++) {
        snprintf (msmFbTypePath, sizeof(msmFbTypePath),
                  "/sys/class/graphics/fb%d/msm_fb_type", j);
        displayDeviceFP = fopen(msmFbTypePath, "r");
        if(displayDeviceFP) {
            fread(fbType, sizeof(char), MAX_FRAME_BUFFER_NAME_SIZE,
                    displayDeviceFP);
            if(strncmp(fbType, "dtv panel", strlen("dtv panel")) == 0) {
                ALOGD("%s: HDMI is at fb%d", __func__, j);
                fclose(displayDeviceFP);
                break;
            }
            fclose(displayDeviceFP);
        } else {
            ALOGE("%s: Failed to open fb node %d", __func__, j);
        }
    }

    if (j < HWC_NUM_DISPLAY_TYPES)
        return j;
    else
        ALOGE("%s: Failed to find HDMI node", __func__);
```

DTV panel is not included in kernel configuration.
The device has from stock the current fb nodes:

- /dev/fb0 (mdss_primary_panel)
- /dev/fb1 (writeback_panel)

So the outcome is the following error in logcat when turning screen on/off:

```
E/qdutils (  269): int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to open fb node 2
E/qdutils (  269): int qdutils::getHDMINode(): Failed to find HDMI node
```

Any ideas on how to disable the /dev/fb2 node searching, or include this feature in kernel/device tree? Some developers say that missing nodes cause latency in screen enabling/disabling when the power key is pressed, so this is a bug I guess.

**SOURCES**

- [Galaxy J5 Common Device Tree on GitHub](https://github.com/Galaxy-J5/android_device_samsung_j5-common)
- [Galaxy J5 CAF Kernel on GitHub](https://github.com/Galaxy-J5/kernel_samsung_j5lte)